# How to load a template into a div of a phtml file in Magento

Tags: jquery, magento

I am trying to load my advanced search template into a div in header.phtml. I don't know how to it exactly. Anybody help me to make it possible.

I am trying to load my advanced search like the feedback in the following link.

[Example](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Feedback-Box-Plugin-with-jQuery-feedBackBox/)

Comment: Please provide more information of what you have tried to do so far.

Comment: I am trying to load my advanced search like the feedback in the following link.


  [1]: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Feedback-Box-Plugin-with-jQuery-feedBackBox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps :

Step 1: First of all open your theme and open the page layout file `/ page.xml`.

Block: `theme­>layout­>page.xml`

Location : `\ app \ design \ frontend \ default \ theme \ layout \ page.xml`

Add your block under this block : `<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header"></block>`

Your Block Code : `<block type="core/template" name="name" template="page/custom.phtml"/>`

**name** is unique name of block and **template** is path of your file.

Now get your block `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>` place where you want to display your block.

Feel free to ask if you have any query.

Comment: Thank you Deepak Mankotia... It was working as I expected. But when I click on the search button within the quick search it was not redirecting and displaying the searced products.

Comment: you need to add the functionality for search on button click

Comment: Thank you once again.. I changed submit button form action. Now its redirecting properly.

Comment: Hi Deepak Mankotia, Only the template is loading. The attributes within the Advanced search were not loading. Please help me to fix it.